# How can I have different values from xcconfig in XCode for sim vs. local vs. hockeyapp?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, development-environment, production-environment, xcconfig

I am working on an app that uses an API. When the app is running in my sim, I want the API server value to be one thing (localhost), when the app is running on my local iphone (plugged into xcode directly), I want to use a different value (staging), and when my app is running via hockeyapp, I want to use a third API server (production). How can I configure things so that I can set properties on my app delegate that are relevant for my current environment? I can do this now by commenting out the other values but this is very error prone.

Comment: Not sure about checking at runtime, however maybe you should look into having multiple schemes or targets that will create a different binary when you build.